# Pass and retrieve array in GraphQL

Tags: javascript, graphql

These days I'm trying to figure out GraphQL, I'm using a mongoDB database on the backend, and a sample report will look something like this,

```
{
    "name" : "Sam",
    "age" : 12,
    "results": {
       "maths" : 43,
       "science": 67,
       "history": 89,
    }
}
```

A report will have an object called results which include multiple object elements

How can I define my GraphQL query to handle the object coming from result object? I can't seem to find an object type that I can use for that.

The GraphQL mutation I tried looks like this,

```
createReport: {
      type: ReportType,
      args: {
        name: {type: GraphQLString},
        age: {type: GraphQLInt},
        results: {type: GraphQLList},
      },
      resolve(parent, args) {
        let report = new reportModel({
          name: args.name,
          age: args.age
          results: args.results
        })

        return investigation.save()
      }
    },
```

But this does not seems to be working, what is the correct GraphQL object or way to handle mogodb object for retrieving and mutations?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you should define its type:

```
// resultsType.js

import * as graphql from 'graphql'
const { GraphQLInputObjectType, GraphQLString } = graphql

export const ResultsType= new GraphQLInputObjectType({
    name: 'resultsType',
    fields: () => ({
        maths: { type: GraphQLInt},
        science: { type: GraphQLInt},
        history: { type: GraphQLInt},
    }),
})
```

and change your code to:

```
createReport: {
      type: ReportType,
      args: {
        name: {type: GraphQLString},
        age: {type: GraphQLInt},
        results: {type: ResultsType},
      },
      resolve(parent, args) {
        let report = new reportModel({
          name: args.name,
          age: args.age
          results: args.results
        })

        return investigation.save()
      }
    },
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will try this out. 
Also what’s the difference between ‘GraphQLObjectType’ vs ‘GraphQLInputObjectType’?

Comment: I made a mistake for mutations we should use GraphQLInputObjectType instead of GraphQLObjectType.